# How to run matlab script on server? or Is there an online matlab interpreter?

Tags: sql-server, matlab, wamp

- I have a matlab script Temp_script.m (say) which,I want to execute on remote 
  server.
- The server(remote) that I am using is free online hosting which gives me 1.5GB storage.
- Since the server is remote one, I have no access to it, to install matlab software or runtime environment.
- locally I can run the matlab script on my server.Obviously because I have matlab installed on my system.
- My question "Is there a method to run the script online.? or Is there
  any online interpreter for matlab?"

Thanking in advance
-Ryaan Dias

Comment: I don't think that's possible... Matlab is not a programming language but a specific program... you have to execute maltab tu unerstand matlab code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Matlab certainly IS a language

Comment: Just a sidenote, typically free hosting websites will not allow you to run anything that requires a significant processing effort. Perhaps you can try to find a list of enabled features and use this to check whether it enables you to run Matlab.

Comment: Try thingspeak.com, although it is targeting for IOT (Internet of Things), it can run MATLAB script, and also have public REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your project using `deploytool`.

This will give you several options, you can make a `dll` and probably even an `exe`.

However, the program is not going to run itself, so if you want it to run automatically on the server you need to have a framework there. Example could be .net but i guess there are easier ones.

Comment: I am aware of deploytool method,say I convert it to java standalone application, but than again i'll need jvm on server to run.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't a web interface for Matlab, and I doubt that the Matlab license would cover such a use case.  However, there you could always try to use the open-source equivalent Octave . Octave can execute Matlab code with only minor modifications.

A quick google search for *Octave Web Server* yielded many results. This was the first hit:http://knn.mimuw.edu.pl/weboctave-project/

Comment: Thanks.I'll try octave but I'm guessing I'll have to install it on server, which I have no access to. :/